# How to de-serialize JSON data into a class and then access the values as class variables and use intellisense to access in Python

Tags: python, json, serialization, deserialization

I have a JSON configuration below

body =

```
{
  "objectId": "068acfee-e5bc-4b27-ad80-59cf0adac4d9",
  "name": "abc",
  "address": {
    "doorNo": 23,
    "pinCode": "456"
  }
}
```

I need to deserialize and access the values in an intuitive way by typing using IntelliSense. Currently I am doing as below

```
import json
class Payload(object):
    def __init__(self, j):
        self.__dict__ = j
```

I am accessing for instance doorNo field as below

```
p = Payload(body)
doorNumber = p.address['doorNo']
```

I wish to access it as below

```
doorNumber = p.address.doorNo
```

How to acheive this way in Python?

In C# I used to achieve this using the Newtonsoft library by de-serializing it into the equivalent class created with respective properties.

```
p = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Payload>(body);
var doorNo = p.address.doorNo
```

> Python Version: 3.9.10
>
> Editor: PyCharm 2022.1 (Community Edition)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `types.SimpleNamespace`

```
import json
from types import SimpleNamespace
your_json_data = '{"a":2, "b":{"c":3"}}'
convt_data = json.loads(your_json_data, object_hook=lambda d: SimpleNamespace(**d))
# you can use it like this -> convt_data.b.c will have value 3
```

Comment: I need to access using intellisense so when I type 'covt_data.' then I need to get options shown by editor

Comment: I have not tried it in intellisense but I think it should work in that as well. Can you try ?

Comment: It works but there is no IntelliSense to show options when you type '.' I am using Pycharm IDE